# MERN stack access control

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, authorization, mern

I've been using MERN stack lastly, I know how to authenticate user (check if he is logged in properly) but I don't really know and feel bit confused when it comes to roles/permissions.

I'm using JWT now and wondering how access control is handled with this stack.

For example with blog, admin should be able to get all registered users from API but regular user or moderator shouldn't.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to put a permission level on the user account and pass only the email in the JWT token, create a middleware in express where it checks if the jwt token is valid and not, if not return status of 401 (unauthorized)

if it passes then decode the jwt and pass the email to express's res.locals as res.locals.email

create another middleware that uses the first middleware, find the user that you want using the email you saved in express's res.local.

findOne user by searching based on email (assuming that email is the unique value), if user is high level then execute a next() function otherwise throw an error 401

validateMiddleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
const token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers.authorization;
if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).send('Access denied.');
}
try {
    const tokenPart = (token as string).split(' ')[1];
    const decode = jwt.verify(tokenPart, String(process.env.JWT_SECRET));
    const userMail = Object(decode).email;
    res.locals.email = userMail;

    next();
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid token' });
}
};
```

authorityMiddleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import user from '../models/modelFunctions/userModelFunction';

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const userData = await user.findOne({ email: res.locals.email });
if (userData.level === 'admin') {
    next();
} else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized, you cannot perform this action');
}
};
```

I have written this in typescript before but you can do the same in javascript just remove the types that I've added

and my jwt will only have the email address nothing more nothing less

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't aware I can do it without auth0 or passport

Comment: @LawlietLawsford it was challenging but keep in mind that this does work only if your intentions using JWT only. If you want to integrate other services then passport is much more recommended otherwise this solutions works